# Factory reset iPad asking for passcode

Tags: ipad, password, bug

I have an iPad Pro that I recently completely wiped and reset (following all of the usual steps correctly) which I am now unable to access without entering a passcode. However no passcode that I've every used is accepted, and I'm unable to proceed.

Why is this happening (how could it possibly happen)? What can I do to get past the passcode and use the iPad?

Comment: what about this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

Comment: @Buscar웃: Why is this happening (how could it possibly happen)?

Comment: sometimes the passcode field is just empty (because you deleted it), so leave it as is and try to continue without entering anything

Comment: @Buscar웃: What do you mean by "continue".